# How to test a Solidity payable contract

Tags: blockchain

I am currently testings an application created using solidity with foundry, and I am wondering how to mock a "payable" function in the tests by a method paying ether to the blockchain. Does anyone know of any built-in functions that would do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to append this : {value: 1 ether}
example: myERC20.mint{value: 1 ether}(10000);

Answer (score -1):

you can use HARDHAT for integrated testing with local devchain.